# f.select Not accepting values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I am using f.select here for these mark up values.

They appear in the drop down but when the form is submitted the value of 1.00 is displayed for any user's choice:

```
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :mark_up %><br>
    <%= f.select :mark_up, options_for_select([[1.00],[1.10],[1.15],[1.20],                    
    [1.25],[1.30],[1.35],[1.40],[1.45],[1.50]],:selected => params[:mark_up]) %> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= f.select(:mark_up, options_for_select([[1.00],[1.10],[1.15],[1.20],                    
[1.25],[1.30],[1.35],[1.40],[1.45],[1.50]], selected: :mark_up )) %>
```

See this link for more info on [rails form helpers - options for select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

Comment: I tried that as well but it return 1 for any value when the form was submitted

Comment: Removing  :selected => params[:mark_up] had no effect, so all values were still present in the dropdown box but no matter what value was chosen 1.0 was submitted

Answer (score 0):

Please the docs for [options_for_select()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) for usage examples.
You can use of both ways:

```
<%= f.select :mark_up, options_for_select([1.00, 1.10, 1.15, 1.20, 1.25, 1.30, 1.35, 1.40, 1.45, 1.50], :selected => f.object.mark_up)
```

or

```
<%= f.select :mark_up, options_for_select([1.00, 1.10, 1.15, 1.20, 1.25, 1.30, 1.35, 1.40, 1.45, 1.50], f.object.mark_up)
```

Comment: Both are still producing the same result